# Is `{` a class?

Tags: r, oop

I am interested in ways of modifying base functions with minimal code in R. I know the `body` function will return the body of any function. So I stored the output of `body(basefoo)` in a variable `bar`. Wanting to know more about how this works, I inspect the class of `bar`. which was `"{"`. I thought that was a strange class. I looked for methods but `methods(class="\\{")` but it says there are no methods.

Is there a reason why the `{` class exists? How can one modify or interact with `{` objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All R code is parsed into a tree before execution (see [Expressions from Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) for more info). In order to have multiple expressions at any point in the tree, R needs to create a wrapper/container to hold those expressions. And that's basically what the `{` class represents. It defines a code block. It's a collection of expressions to be evaluated. Think if it like a function where each expression you want to evaluate is a parameter (at least that's how it's stored in the tree). And code blocks simply return the value returned by the last expression. Compare

```
as.list(quote({a; b}))
# [[1]]
# `{`
# [[2]]
# a
# [[3]]
# b
as.list(quote(c(a, b)))
# [[1]]
# c
# [[2]]
# a
# [[3]]
# b
```

See how they are turned into similar structures in R? The "function name" is first followed by the list of parameters. You can even call `{` like a regular function

```
`{`(a<-1, 5, a+2)
# [1] 3
```

(note how the last value is the only one returned). Also note that code blocks do not create their own scope so the variable `a` will be defined in the global environment if you run this at the console.

You can create an object of this type by just quoting a code block

```
class(xx <- quote({a; b}))
# [1] "{"
xx
# {
#     a
#     b
# }
```

or by building a call with quoted symbols

```
class(xx <- as.call(list(quote(`{`), quote(a), quote(b))))
# [1] "{"
xx
# {
#     a
#     b
# }
```

And it's not always the case the body of a function will be of `{` class. For example

```
x <- function(a) a+1
y <- function(a) {b <- sqrt(a); b+2}
class(body(x))
# [1] "call"
class(body(y))
# [1] "{"
```

because we wanted to run more than one statement in the `y` function we had to put those expressions in a code block. Since `x` is only calling one expression we didn't need to use `{` so it has a different class.

Comment: Wonderfully helpful! Thank you. The link and your explanation has helped me understand this, as well as the use of `quote`. With that, I was able to make small modifications of base and package code, and I understand better how that works. Thanks again!